# Split a vector Into Some Overlapping Number of Subvectors With the following Conditions

Tags: r, vector, split

I want to split a vector into subvectors with the following:
g conditions:

1. Each sub-vector has an equal length `l` which is less than the number
   of the parent vector `v`.
2. Each sub-vector is unique in its elements' composition and contains
   consecutive elements.
3. Elements of a particular sub-vector overlap with elements of
   previous and subsequent sub-vector.
4. No subvector must start with the position of an element that is divisible by `l`. Take for instance, if `l=2` no subvector must start `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ..., n`, for `l=3` no subvector must start `3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, ..., n`, for `l=3` no subvector must start `4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, ..., n` etc.
5. The input should be a vector for the parent vector `v`, and an
   integer for the block length `l`. While the output should be a list
   of vectors (not a matrix) such that each sub-vector is output as a
   vector and the list of all sub-vectors is a list.

The below code shows a case where the `conditiontion 4` above is not applied.

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) # the parent vector
l <- 3 # constant length of sub-vectors to be
m <- length(v) - l + 1 # number of sub-vector to be
split(t(embed(v, m))[m:1,], 1:m)

$`1`
[1] 1 2 3

$`2`
[1] 2 3 4

$`3`
[1] 3 4 5

$`4`
[1] 4 5 6

$`5`
[1] 5 6 7

$`6`
[1] 6 7 8

$`7`
[1] 7 8 9

$`8`
[1]  8  9 10
```

The result I have in the above code will now be worked open by manually removing the subvectors that violate `condition number 4` above.

I know that my number of subvectors should be `length(ts) - l + 1 - floor((length(ts) - l + 1)/l)` but when I tried the code below:

**What I Want**

```
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3

$`2`
[1] 2 3 4

$`3`
[1] 4 5 6

$`4`
[1] 5 6 7

$`5`
[1] 7 8 9

$`6`
[1]  8  9 10
```

The result must satisfy my `number 4 condition` and every other.

For illustration, consider a parent vector of `x1` to `x10` with a subvector size of `l = 3` consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
x1, x2, x3
    x2, x3, x4
            x4, x5, x6
                x5, x6, x7
                        x7, x8, x9
                            x8, x9, x10
```

What I do is form a series of subvectors each with length `l =3` with starting elements being progressive in nature (`x1, x2 x4, x5, x7, x8, x10`) and not recursive. The third sub-vector starts from `x4` and not `x3` because starting it from `x3` will make `x3` 3 a position of the original vector that is divisible by `l = 3`. The same consideration is applied to the 6th and the supposed 7th sub-vector.

**How I Need It**

I need an `R` code that gives me the output I want according to the conditions above. You can use `v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)` for parent vector input with your choice of `1 < l < length(v)` in your `R code` test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibillity would be to create an empty list and append each subvector only if its first element is not divisible by `l` . Then we remove all `NULL` elements from the created list.

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) # the parent vector
l <- 3 # constant length of sub-vectors to be
m <- length(v) - l + 1 # number of sub-vector to be

li <- vector("list",m)

for (i in 1:m) {
  if (v[i]%%l) {
    li[[i]] <- v[i:(i+l-1)]
  }
}

> Filter(Negate(is.null),li)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[4]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[5]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[6]]
[1]  8  9 10
```

Or as a function :

```
kmers <- function(v,k) {
  m <- (length(v)-k+1)
  li <- vector("list",m)
  for (i in 1:m) {
    if (v[i]%%k) {
      li[[i]] <- v[i:(i+k-1)]
    }
  }
  Filter(Negate(is.null),li)
}

> kmers(v,3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[4]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[5]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[6]]
[1]  8  9 10
```

This is not an very " `R`" typicall solution, maybe there is something more elegant, but its not a very R typical problem either.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this helps

```
m1 <- embed(c(v, v), 3)[seq_len(m), l:1]
 asplit(m1[!!m1[,1] %% l,], 1)
```

-output

```
[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[4]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[5]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[6]]
[1]  8  9 10
```

Comment: Try your answer with `l = 2` it prints `Error in embed(c(v, v), 2)[seq_len(m), l:1] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: Amazing vocabulary! In 20 ys of using R, this is the first time I encountered `asplit` and `embed`.

Comment: @DanielJames I couldn't get that error with l= 2, have you updated the `m` based on the `l` value?

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
parent <- paste0('x', 1:10)
len <- 3

subvectors <- 
  outer(seq_along(parent), 
        seq_len(len),
        \(x, y) parent[-1 + x + y]
        ) |>
  (`[`)(which(seq_along(parent) %% len != 0),) |>
      apply(1, c, simplify = F)
```

```
## > subvectors
[[1]]
[1] "x1" "x2" "x3"

[[2]]
[1] "x2" "x3" "x4"

[[3]]
[1] "x4" "x5" "x6"
##
```